# Как поменять иконку при нажатии на кнопку JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

Всем привет! Можете пожалуйста помочь с кодом, мне нужно поменять иконку на кнопке при нажатии, всё перепробовал, но ничего не работает!

Подскажите, что не так со скриптом JS?

```js
let div = document.querySelector(".musicbutton");
let btn = document.querySelector(".musicicon");
let icon = btn.querySelector(".fa-solid fa-volume-high");

div.onclick = function () {
  if (icon.classList.contains("fa-solid fa-volume-high")) {
    icon.classList.replace(
      "fa-solid fa-volume-high",
      "fa-solid fa-volume-slash"
    );
  } else {
    icon.classList.replace(
      "fa-solid fa-volume-slash",
      "fa-solid fa-volume-high"
    );
  }
};
```

```css
.musicbutton {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 40px;
  
}

.musicon {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 4px solid #FF3C3C;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.fa-solid.fa-volume-high {
color: #FF3C3C;
font-size: 40px;
}

.musicon:hover {
filter: drop-shadow(0px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
border: 4px solid #31b837;
transition: 1s;
transform: scale(1.5);
}

.musicon:not(:hover) {
transition: 1s;
}

.fa-solid.fa-volume-high:hover {
  color:#31b837;
  transition: 1s;
}

.fa-solid.fa-volume-high:not(:hover) {
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="musicbutton">
        <button class="musicon">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-volume-high"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас ошибки в селекторах.

Ищите `document.querySelector(".musicicon")`, а компонент называется `musicon`.

В `btn.querySelector(".fa-solid fa-volume-high")`, точка потерялась и лишний пробел, должно быть `".fa-solid.fa-volume-high"`

В обработчике `onclick`, вместо сложной конструкции `if ... else ...`, используйте метод [toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle).